# Add an image id by finding the image alt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

There is an image without an id on a page that I can't manually access to change the html. I'd like to be able to add an id value in a javascript file that I do have access to.

I found this thread:

[Finding An image tag using the alt text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914456/finding-an-image-tag-using-the-alt-text)

And this one:

[Replace image and image title/alt text with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003292/replace-image-and-image-title-alt-text-with-javascript)

And I've been trying a few variations to get it to work.

Can someone show me where I'm going wrong? I'm currently using:

```
$('img[alt="close_pop"]').attr('id','close');
```

I don't think I'm fully understanding, as this is what I thought it was doing:

```
$('img[alt="close_pop"]') //getting the image based on the alt tag using jquery.

.attr('id','close'); //then I was applying a new id to that image.
```

All help appreciated!

Comment: Why isn't your solution working?

Comment: The id isn't added to the img as I thought it would be

Comment: how are you testing to see if the id is added?

Comment: The javascript is on page load, so I refresh the page and check whether or not the id has been added to the image. I have a console.log in there to make sure it is hitting that bit of the javascript file on load which it is.

Comment: Did you try using prop() in place of attr()?

Comment: _"The javascript is on page load, so I refresh the page and check whether or not the id has been added to the image."_ Page "refresh" loading original `html` from  _"a page that I can't manually access to change the html"_ ? , without `id` added by `js` before refresh occurred ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the element and search for the id. It gets alt's value:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var img = $('img[alt="test"]');
  var alt = img.attr('alt');
  console.log(alt);
  img.attr('id', alt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img alt="test" src="" />
```

Comment: Solved the issue - thanks! Will mark as correct answer when time is up.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="smiley.gif" class="smile" id="smiley" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">



 $(window).load(function(){
    $("img").click(function() {
        var img = $("img[alt='Smiley face']");
        img.attr("id", "fool");
        console.log(img.attr("id"));
    });
    });
```